main content is right justified unless it has large(ish) content
I have an SPA where the main view is a header, navbar and responsive content in the main body of the HTML.
The content comprises one or more <article>s (I've swapped these to <div>s and it's made no difference) which,
when they have a decent amount of content (~100 characters or more) the articles correctly display left to right
and respond to the screen resizing.
But when they only have a small amount of content they become right justified.
Not working - right justified (small content in each article):

Working correctly - left justified (larger content in each article):


Here's a cut down version of the HTML and CSS that replicates the problem (I've removed the side navbar, which makes
no difference to the behaviour.
These examples show the problem - fill in the <p>...</p> content with lorum ipsum text to
see the problem go away.


:root{
    --base-clr: #11121a;
    --header-clr: #8a918c;
    --header-text-clr: #2d302e;
    --line-clr: #42434a;
    --hover-clr: #222533;
    --text-clr: #e6e6ef;
    --accent-clr: #5e63ff;
    --secondary-text-clr: #b0b3c1;
    --header-bar-height: 40px;
}
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html{
    font-family: Poppins, 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
}

body{
    min-height: 100vh;
    min-height: 100dvh;
    background-color: var(--base-clr);
    color: var(--text-clr);
}

#spa {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:
    "header navbar content";
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
}

main{
    grid-area: content;
    padding: min(30px, 7%);
    min-height: calc(100vh - var(--header-bar-height));
}

main p{
    color: var(--secondary-text-clr);
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}


article{
    border: 1px solid var(--line-clr);
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    border-radius: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: min(3em, 15%);

    h2, p { margin-top: 1em }
}
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <title>GridCss</title>
    <link href="./app.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
        <div id="spa">
            <header>
                Header
            </header>

            <main>
                <div class="grid">
                    <article>
                        <img src="https://www.mig-welding.co.uk/forum/data/avatars/s/40/40757.jpg" alt="Sample photo">
                        <div class="text">
                            <h3>Seamlessly visualize quality</h3>
                            <p>small text</p>
                            <button>Here's why</button>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                    <article>
                        <img src="https://www.mig-welding.co.uk/forum/data/avatars/s/40/40757.jpg" alt="Sample photo">
                        <div class="text">
                            <h3> Seamlessly visualize quality</h3>
                            <p>tiny</p>
                            <button>Here's why</button>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                </div>
            </main>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>


</html>




Edit:
The solution from @pr0f3ss0r has addressed this main question, but there's now a secondary issue. They recommended removing the outer <spa> wrapper and CSS but, without that, the page is propagating a display: block; to the <main> code, which has the effect of pushing the content below the side bar.
Here's what it looks like without the <spa> wrapper and CSS:

I can half-fix this, by reintroducing a wrapper and setting its display: grid;...

This is why I thought the grid needed to be on an outer object, because it had to set positions of three pieces of content; header, navbar and main
Edit2: Second code snippet added
Original issue of right alignment fixed, but main content appears below the 100vh viewport window.


:root{
    --base-clr: #11121a;
    --header-clr: #8a918c;
    --header-text-clr: #2d302e;
    --line-clr: #42434a;
    --hover-clr: #222533;
    --text-clr: #e6e6ef;
    --accent-clr: #5e63ff;
    --secondary-text-clr: #b0b3c1;
    --header-bar-height: 40px;
}
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html{
    font-family: Poppins, 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
}

body{
    min-height: 100vh;
    min-height: 100dvh;
    background-color: var(--base-clr);
    color: var(--text-clr);
}

.grid{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:    "header navbar content";
}

header{
    grid-area: header;
    height: var(--header-bar-height);
    width: 100%;
    border-right: none;
    border-top: 1px solid var(--line-clr);
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    background-color: var(--header-clr);
    color: var(--header-text-clr);
}

main{
    grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
    display:flex;
    grid-area: content;
    padding: min(30px, 7%);
    box-sizing:border-box;

}

main p{
    color: var(--secondary-text-clr);
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}


article{
    border: 1px solid var(--line-clr);
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    border-radius: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: min(3em, 15%);

    h2, p { margin-top: 1em }

}

#sidebar{
    grid-area: navbar;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: calc(100vh - var(--header-bar-height));
    width: 250px;
    padding: 5px 1em;
    background-color: var(--base-clr);
    border-right: 1px solid var(--line-clr);

    position: sticky;
    top: var(--header-bar-height);
    align-self: start;
    transition: 300ms ease-in-out;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-wrap: nowrap;
}
#sidebar.close{
    padding: 5px;
    width: 60px;
}
#sidebar ul{
    list-style: none;
}
#sidebar > ul > li:first-child{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    .logo{
        font-weight: 600;
    }
}
#sidebar ul li.active a{
    color: var(--accent-clr);

    svg{
        fill: var(--accent-clr);
    }
}

#sidebar a, #sidebar .nav-dropdown-btn, #sidebar .logo{
    border-radius: .5em;
    padding: .85em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--text-clr);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 1em;
}
.nav-dropdown-btn{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    font: inherit;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#sidebar svg{
    flex-shrink: 0;
    fill: var(--text-clr);
}
#sidebar a span, #sidebar .nav-dropdown-btn span{
    flex-grow: 1;
}
#sidebar a:hover, #sidebar .nav-dropdown-btn:hover{
    background-color: var(--hover-clr);
}
#sidebar .sub-menu{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 0fr;
    transition: 300ms ease-in-out;

    > div{
        overflow: hidden;
    }
}
#sidebar .sub-menu.show{
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}
.nav-dropdown-btn svg{
    transition: 200ms ease;
}
.rotate svg:last-child{
    rotate: 180deg;
}
#sidebar .sub-menu a{
    padding-left: 2em;
}
#sidebar-toggle-btn{
    margin-left: auto;
    padding: 1em;
    border: none;
    border-radius: .5em;
    background: none;
    cursor: pointer;

    svg{
        transition: rotate 150ms ease;
    }
}
#sidebar-toggle-btn:hover{
    background-color: var(--hover-clr);
}
<header>
    Header
</header>

    <nav id="sidebar">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <span class="logo">coding2go</span>
                <button onclick=toggleSidebar() id="sidebar-toggle-btn">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24px" viewBox="0 -960 960 960" width="24px"
                         fill="#e8eaed">
                        <path
                                d="m313-480 155 156q11 11 11.5 27.5T468-268q-11 11-28 11t-28-11L228-452q-6-6-8.5-13t-2.5-15q0-8 2.5-15t8.5-13l184-184q11-11 27.5-11.5T468-692q11 11 11 28t-11 28L313-480Zm264 0 155 156q11 11 11.5 27.5T732-268q-11 11-28 11t-28-11L492-452q-6-6-8.5-13t-2.5-15q0-8 2.5-15t8.5-13l184-184q11-11 27.5-11.5T732-692q11 11 11 28t-11 28L577-480Z"/>
                    </svg>
                </button>
            </li>
            <li class="active">
                <a href="/">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24px" viewBox="0 -960 960 960" width="24px"
                         fill="#e8eaed">
                        <path
                                d="M240-200h120v-200q0-17 11.5-28.5T400-440h160q17 0 28.5 11.5T600-400v200h120v-360L480-740 240-560v360Zm-80 0v-360q0-19 8.5-36t23.5-28l240-180q21-16 48-16t48 16l240 180q15 11 23.5 28t8.5 36v360q0 33-23.5 56.5T720-120H560q-17 0-28.5-11.5T520-160v-200h-80v200q0 17-11.5 28.5T400-120H240q-33 0-56.5-23.5T160-200Zm320-270Z"/>
                    </svg>
                    <span>Home</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/playerDetails">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24px" viewBox="0 -960 960 960" width="24px"
                         fill="#e8eaed">
                        <path
                                d="M480-480q-66 0-113-47t-47-113q0-66 47-113t113-47q66 0 113 47t47 113q0 66-47 113t-113 47ZM160-240v-32q0-34 17.5-62.5T224-378q62-31 126-46.5T480-440q66 0 130 15.5T736-378q29 15 46.5 43.5T800-272v32q0 33-23.5 56.5T720-160H240q-33 0-56.5-23.5T160-240Zm80 0h480v-32q0-11-5.5-20T700-306q-54-27-109-40.5T480-360q-56 0-111 13.5T260-306q-9 5-14.5 14t-5.5 20v32Zm240-320q33 0 56.5-23.5T560-640q0-33-23.5-56.5T480-720q-33 0-56.5 23.5T400-640q0 33 23.5 56.5T480-560Zm0-80Zm0 400Z"/>
                    </svg>
                    <span>Profile</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <main>
        <div class="grid">
            <article>
                <img src="https://www.mig-welding.co.uk/forum/data/avatars/s/40/40757.jpg" alt="Sample photo">
                <div class="text">
                    <h3>Seamlessly visualize quality</h3>
                    <p>Hello</p>
                    <button>Here's why</button>
                </div>
            </article>
            <article>
                <img src="https://www.mig-welding.co.uk/forum/data/avatars/s/40/40757.jpg" alt="Sample photo">
                <div class="text">
                    <h3> Seamlessly visualize quality</h3>
                    <p>Hello</p>
                    <button>Here's why</button>
                </div>
            </article>
        </div>
    </main>




Once in a blue moon, someone posts their markup here and they aren't using a doctype which caused their problem. You are using a doctype, right?

Yes I am - this is just an extract from a much larger codebase, where I manually recreated the ... part. So good catch, but that's not it!



:root{
    --base-clr: #11121a;
    --header-clr: #8a918c;
    --header-text-clr: #2d302e;
    --line-clr: #42434a;
    --hover-clr: #222533;
    --text-clr: #e6e6ef;
    --accent-clr: #5e63ff;
    --secondary-text-clr: #b0b3c1;
    --header-bar-height: 40px;
}
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html{
    font-family: Poppins, 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
}

body{
    min-height: 100vh;
    min-height: 100dvh;
    background-color: var(--base-clr);
    color: var(--text-clr);
}

.grid{
    display: grid;
  padding:auto;
    grid-template-areas:
    "header navbar content";
   
  
}

main{
   grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  display:flex;
    grid-area: content;
    padding: min(30px, 7%);
  box-sizing:border-box;
    
}

main p{
    color: var(--secondary-text-clr);
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}


article{
    border: 1px solid var(--line-clr);
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    border-radius: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: min(3em, 15%);

    h2, p { margin-top: 1em }
  
}
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <title>GridCss</title>
    <link href="./app.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>

<body>
   
        
            <header>
                Header
            </header>

            <main>
                <div class="grid">
                    <article>
                        <img src="https://www.mig-welding.co.uk/forum/data/avatars/s/40/40757.jpg" alt="Sample photo">
                        <div class="text">
                            <h3>Seamlessly visualize quality</h3>
                            <p>small text</p>
                            <button>Here's why</button>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                    <article>
                        <img src="https://www.mig-welding.co.uk/forum/data/avatars/s/40/40757.jpg" alt="Sample photo">
                        <div class="text">
                            <h3> Seamlessly visualize quality</h3>
                            <p>tiny</p>
                            <button>Here's why</button>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                </div>
            </main>

       
   
</body>


</html>



Remove unnecessary wrappers like 'spa' and 'app'. Use display:grid on the 'grid' class to make div stand side by side.
Use display:flex on the 'main' wrapper to expand box when more content is added.

Thanks so much for that - this does address the question I'd asked, however (the downside of cutting back the example...) removing the outer #spa wrapper with "display: grid" causes the main content to be pushed below the navbar. I'll post a follow-on comment with the secondary problem.

Ah - I can't add a new comment with snippet, etc. so have edited my original question. Any additional thoughts would be greatly appreciated - @pr0f3ss0r

I think you should set your left margin to the width size of your nav. for example, margin-left: 20px; something like that.
